# Gain reference to button that launched jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have a page with a variable number of tables which are dynamically generated. Each table lists a group of "products" which the user can add/edit/delete. Underneath each table is a button. I want each button to save the products in the table above it to a "package", which is just a group of products. When the button is clicked, I want it to launch a jQuery dialog form where a user can enter a name and description for the package that they're creating.

Is there a way for me to get a reference to the button that launched the jQuery dialog in the first place within the scope of the dialog's "buttons" functions? That way, when the user clicks the "save" button in the dialog, I can submit both the form that is contained in the dialog itself (name and description) AND also submit the product data that is contained within the table closest in the page markup to the particular button that the user clicked to launch the form?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the WHOLE page (all tables) are already contained within one form element. This is because a user can also save all of the products in the three tables as an "oportunity", which is a group of groups of products. Here is a little pseudo html to show the layout:

```
<form>
    <table>
    </table>
    <table>
    </table>
    <table>
    </table>
</form>
```

For the purpose of allowing user to save all products in all of the tables to an "opportunity", I need to leave all three tables wrapped in one form tag. However, when a user clicks the "save package" button under a particular table, I want to only submit the data in that one table and the name and description entered by the user in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a global variable in js and set its  value if one of the button's clicked.
in this example "id" is used .

```
$('.button').click(function(){
   id = $(this).index();
   $('#dialog').fadeIn('1000');
    return false;
});
```

maybe this can be helpful :
http://jsfiddle.net/Vm7PL/1/

also you can use jquery-ui dialog box .

Answer (score 0):

not sure what type of button you are using, but here is with the standard html input submit button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);

        //get the TR the button is in
        var tr = btn.parent().parent(); // first parent will be the TD, second will be TR, third would be the TABLE

        // find other elements in the TR
        tr.find('#someElement').each(function(){
            //do something with the elements
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't address the issue I'm having. There are two buttons that are involved in my problem, one that has a click event which launches a jQuery dialog with a form inside, and one _within_ the jQuery dialog that should submit the form contained within the dialog, as well as the data from the table closest in markup to the _first_ button. I know how to reference the table closest to the first button within the click event for the first button, as you do above. What I don't know how to do is reference the first button from within the button function of the jQuery dialog.

Comment: i guess i don't understand what is on the first button that you need. if you can get all of the data from the two forms, then what is the first button giving you?